# Android Jetpack Compose open street map conflict with tabrow

Tags: android, kotlin, dictionary, android-jetpack-compose, osmdroid

I am trying compose but something went wrong...
I have TabScreen with two tabs (Map and Monitors). Tab Monitors work fine but tab Map work wrong. When I switch tab Map, my tabrow disappear but I try click to place for tabrow, its work and switching.

TabScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun TabScreen() {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val tabs = listOf("Map", "Monitors")

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            divider = {
                TabRowDefaults.Divider(
                    Modifier.wrapContentSize(Alignment.BottomStart),
                    color = Color(0xFFF4F4F4)
                )
            },
            indicator = { tabPositions: List<TabPosition> ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[tabIndex]),
                    color = Color.Yellow,
                    height = 4.dp
                )
            },
            contentColor = Color(0xFFC2C2C2)
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    text = { Text(title) },
                    selected = tabIndex == index,
                    onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                    selectedContentColor = Color.Black,
                    unselectedContentColor = Color(0xFFC2C2C2)
                )
            }
        } 
        
        when (tabIndex) {
            0 -> MapScreen()
            1 -> MonitorsScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

MonitorsScreen work fine:

[image: [MonitorsScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDBw8.jpg)]

MapScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun MapScreen() {
    Box() {
        val context = LocalContext.current

        val cameraState = rememberCameraState {
            geoPoint = GeoPoint(-6.3970066, 106.8224316)
            zoom = 12.0
        }

        var mapProperties by remember {
            mutableStateOf(DefaultMapProperties)
        }

        val overlayManagerState = rememberOverlayManagerState()

        SideEffect {
            mapProperties = mapProperties
                .copy(isTilesScaledToDpi = true)
                .copy(tileSources = TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
                .copy(isEnableRotationGesture = true)
                .copy(zoomButtonVisibility = ZoomButtonVisibility.NEVER)
        }

        OpenStreetMap(
//        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            cameraState = cameraState,
            properties = mapProperties,
            overlayManagerState = overlayManagerState,
            onFirstLoadListener = {
                val copyright = CopyrightOverlay(context)
                overlayManagerState.overlayManager.add(copyright)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image: [MapScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkdKZ.jpg)]

If I touch map, part tabrow showing:

[image: [MapScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRxC7.jpg)]

what am I doing wrong ?

I want in result:
[image: [MapScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hd4P.jpg)]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `clipToOutline = true` on your MapView object.

Here you can find a full [example](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1674).